# Name of function that maps to input set

Tags: functions, terminology

Let $f: S \rightarrow S$ be a function and $S$ be a set. $S$ is not the underlying set of a vector space. Most likely, it is also not the underlying set of a topology (though I am not sure). It would be best to say that it is just any set. With what *word* can I denote that $f$ maps the input to elements of the *same* set?

These are not it:

- *Homeomorphism* refers to [continuous function between topological spaces that has a continuous inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism), but I don't know whether there is an inverse function, and it certainly is not continuous.
- A [*surjective* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) or a *injective* function maps between potentially different sets.

Comment: You could say, "$f$ is an endomorphism of the set $S$".

Comment: @user816709: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism says "An endofunction is a function whose domain is equal to its codomain. A homomorphic endofunction is an endomorphism." To speak about a homorophism, I would require an algebraic structure over "S". Doesn't that mean that "endofunction" is actually more correct than "endomorophism"?

Comment: What I just wrote, seems to be denied by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism#Automorphisms, since there a homomorphism is considered to be a special case of an endomorphism.

Comment: I've never seen "endofunction" used in introductory textbooks (which are all I've ever read), so make of that what you will.

Yes, the notion of endomorphisms applies to sets, groups, topological spaces, and really any other mathematical category. So, unless it's implied, it's safest to say "endomorphism of a set".

Comment: @user816709: Thanks! An endomorphism is a morphism (I guess) and a morphism must be structure-preserving. I am not quite sure I understand that correctly, but I don't want to assume my set to have any structure in the first place. Is endomorphism still correct and if yes, why?

Comment: That's correct. While it's a nice heuristic to think of morphisms in a category as structure-preserving, it's not the precise definition. When we're working in the category of sets, morphisms (and hence endomorphisms) are defined to be regular old functions. If you must, you can think of sets as having "no structure" to preserve, so that any function is considered a morphism.